# how to invoke array-list dynamically?

Tags: java, android

How to invoke Array-name from IPSUM.java class to **updateArticleView** method by passing its name simply?
eg. in highlighted row, i want to achieve this `article.setText(Ipsum.LateralPull[0]);` dynamically

**updateArticleView method**

[image]

**IPSUM.java**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do that is to use a `HashMap<String, String[]>` and you can put each array to the map with its current field name as its key:

```
map.put("LateralPull", new String[]{"LateralPaull"});
```

So you can simply call:

```
map.get(name);
```

But If you don't want to use HashMap for any reason you can use java reflection. Here is a sample code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Test test = new Test();
        Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        String[] list = (String[]) field.get(test);
        System.out.println(list[0]);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("hasahn", new String[]{"df"});



}

private static class Test{
    String[] list = new String[]{"Item 1"};
}
}
```

The output is: Item 1.

Comment: cool, i will try it now. And let u know if it work for my app